# Why is my tensorboard graph like a Sawtooth waveform instead of a continuous line?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

Here is a code that I implemented to plot an array on tensorboard:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = [100, 80, 50, 40, 30, 15, 10, 7, 5, 9, 3, 1]
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./log')
summary = tf.Summary()

for i in range (0, len(a)):
    summary.value.add(tag='x', simple_value=a[i])
    writer.add_summary(summary, i)
    writer.flush()

writer.close()
```

I get a plot like this: [Tensorbaord plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xllj1.png)

I want something like the blue line but instead I get the orange line. Please help me spot a mistake in my code and also state a reason for such behaviour? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are adding the same values again and again to the summary. Instead you could do

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = [100, 80, 50, 40, 30, 15, 10, 7, 5, 9, 3, 1]
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./log')

for i in range (0, len(a)):
    summary = tf.Summary()
    summary.value.add(tag='x', simple_value=a[i])
    writer.add_summary(summary, i)

writer.close()
```

Comment: Yes, it worked, Thanks a lot. I'll keep that in mind.